# Multithreading JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, multithreading, io

I need to process a large amount of JSON-files and I want to multithread this processing. However, I find that multithreading doesn't improve the processing time at all and in fact takes the same amount of time as if done in serial.

I have narrowed the issue down to this piece of code, where the JSON files are parsed:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as th
import json

def func(file_names):
    for file in file_names:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            x = json.loads(f.read())


N_THREADS = 2
file_names = [.....]  # list of file names

with th(N_THREADS) as ex:
    ex.map(func, file_names)
```

Based on this, it seems that parsing JSON-files is done in serial. Why can't this be multithreaded using `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Is there another way of multithreading this?

Comment: (1) I doubt that the shown code would work at all if `file_names` is just a list of strings. (2) Generally, Python isn't good at multithreading (because of the global interpreter lock). Try multiprocessing instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you read all the files in every thread, `func` should handle a single file

```
def func(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        x = json.load(f)


N_THREADS = 2
file_names = [.....]  # list of file names

with th(N_THREADS) as ex:
    ex.map(func, file_names)
```